# Установка пути для Web-службы во время выполнения

Tags: c#, .net

Есть два экземпляра сервиса wcf, 1 развернут на продакшне и 2 локальный для отладки. Сейчас для переключения между ними нужно перед компиляцией удалять и заново добавлять ссылку в ConnectedServices. Как во время выполнения можно указать клиенту сервер, на котором работает сервис? 
Вот [тут](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12317/How-to-make-your-Web-Reference-proxy-URL-dynamic) есть описание решения проблемы, но у меня (VS 2017) всё выглядит иначе: в Reference.cs адрес хоста заменен на http://tempuri.org и в свойствах ссылки нет параметра URL Behavior.

Comment: А разве в  конструкторе клиента нельзя указать конечную точку? А саму настройку вынесите в АппКонфиг.

Comment: Да, вы абсолютно правы, так в итоге и сделал.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Спасибо [iluxa1810](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/32793/iluxa1810), в итоге получилось что-то вроде

```
    #if DEBUG
        Uri serviceUri = new Uri("http://localhost/TPService.svc");
    #else
        Uri serviceUri = new Uri("http://productionserver/TPService.svc");
    #endif
        EndpointAddress EndpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(serviceUri);
        ChannelFactory<ITPService> serviceFactory = new ChannelFactory<ITPService>(new BasicHttpBinding(), EndpointAddress);
        ITPService serviceInstance = serviceFactory.CreateChannel();
```